# Get any element

Tags: dhtmlx

I am using DHTMLX, and I have output that goes to a div.  The text gets into the div using "attachHTMLString", but after it's in that div, I don't know how to access it.

I'm used to using jQuery where you can assign an ID or class and traverse the DOM and get it.  With DHTMLX, it's like jQuery's powers are useless.  I just cannot get the data that is right in front of me.

I'm looking for something like:

```
var divText = dhtmlxElement.getText();
```

What's the secret to traversing the DHTMLX elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured out, the way to do it is to give the element an ID when it's created.  Later, you can just call it out by ID.

What apparently does NOT work is to refer to the element on the page by its DHTMLX name and try to "get" it, or capture its text.

Answer (score 0):

But what component are you asking about? 
I.e. you can really get the text of tree node by ID...

```
var text = tree.getItemText("itemId");
```

And many other components provide this feature